# Send Firebase auth token to nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, http-headers

i want to let the client login with firebase through the front-end. later i want to send the token that verifies that he's logged in to my server, so that i can check if some info about him on the database. e.g: if he paid for a specific course.

the firebase documentation doesn't provide actual code on how to send it to my own server:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
  // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
  // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle error
});
```

so, i'm looking for an idea or preferably some code on how to send the token to the server with each request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways you can do it. I like using Axios https://github.com/axios/axios

```
axios.post('/your-endpoint', {
    token: your-token
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: But how do I put the token on every request? Or I don't have to do this?

Comment: I might need to see more of your code to fully understand your problem. Why cant you just add the token in to each request to your server?

Comment: I think u managed to do that with sessions / cookie... Do you think there is a better way?